# Customize wordpress oEmbedd (soundcloud)

Tags: wordpress, soundcloud

I am using Wordpress 4.3.1 and I noticed that it used oEmbed to automatically embed my tracks from soundcloud.

This is awesome! Except, I have no control over how the widget is displayed.

First of all I would like to display the "Classic Embed" without the artwork.

Secondly I want the widget to be wider.

How can I achieve this without editing the shortcode for each post in my wordpress page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a filter to change the way the oEmbed code is displayed. Here is something to get you started:

`// this function is called on all urls surrounded by the WordPress embed shortcode.
// i.e.: [embed]https://soundcloud.com/gratefuldead/grateful-dead-box-of-rain[/embed]
function my_embed_options( $code ) {
    // look for SoundCloud link:
    if( strpos( $code, 'soundcloud.com') !== false ) {
        $code = str_replace( 'show_artwork=true', 'show_artwork=false', $code );
    }
    return $code;
}
add_filter( 'embed_oembed_html', 'my_embed_options' );`

You can find full parameter list for the SoundCloud player [here](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/widget).